# Liinux HTB Qos filter is not working as expected

Tags: filter

i am experimenting linux qos with  htb and u32

i trying to create a rule with multiple qdiscs

please see below script and  tell me where i am doing wrong ?

i am expecting 192.168.1.111 to have only 1 mbit download yet dude gets almost 100 mbit

```
tc qdisc del dev eth1 root

tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 20mbit
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 10mbit

tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:2 handle 2: htb
tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:3 handle 3: htb 
tc class add dev eth1 parent 3: classid 3:1 htb rate 2mbit
tc class add dev eth1 parent 3:1 classid 3:2 htb rate 1mbit

tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 3: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 192.168.1.111/32 flowid 3:2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 3: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 192.168.1.111/32 flowid 3:2
```

was not enough it needed parent side filter as well

```
tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 192.168.1.111/32 flowid 1:3
```

it is now working as expected